# How to find only the negative Imaginary solutions and positive Real solutions?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

Following this post [Help Please : Error in plotting the solutions of FindRoot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65902/help-please-error-in-plotting-the-solutions-of-findroot)
, I want to plot only the negative Imaginary solutions Wi(K)<0 and positive Real solutions Wr(K)>0.

Please, how do it?

Thank's

Comment: Please read the comment @DanielLichtblau posted in your other question

Comment: @belisarius Please how do it ?